# SAPUI5 Smart table error - Select at least one column to perform the search

Tags: sapui5

I am encountering an error ***Select at least one column to perform the search*** when using a smart table to display data.

I have developed an annotation based gateway service and everything looks fine with the metadata structure. Please see this [link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3960674) for my metadata and view files

Kind ragards

Answer (score 0):

the entity-set you are choosing must be improper.

```js
entitySet="/yourentityset"
   smartFilterId="smartFilterBar"
```

check for the smartFilterId . You error may occur due to the wrong filter id or the entityset 
try to debug in the network part and check if you are getting the destination or the metadata

Comment: Hi Gopal

I am getting the metadata and I have specified smartFilterId="smartFilterBar". EntitySet is correct. Still getting the error. Is there any other way of displaying subtotals in a table besides using a smart table?

Comment: Hi willard You can use normal table under the head of smart table. And perform the operations over the code.   `<smartTable:SmartTable entitySet="/path"
   smartFilterId="smartFilterBar"  useExportToExcel="true"
   useVariantManagement="true" useTablePersonalisation="true" 
   showRowCount="false" >
   
    <Table id="table"  items="{/path}"
      growing="true" 
      growingThreshold="6"
      growingScrollToLoad="false"
      >  </smartchart:smartchart>`  this will help-out in filtering the table columns and also you can implement things like you do in normal table

Answer (score 0):

Probably u had empty property `initiallyVisibleFields = ""`. I forced it today.
Or you have custom columns without `"leadingProperty": "property_name"`.